# Javascript: Calculate width of div as sum of images

Tags: javascript

Basically, I need "style="width:__" to be added to the "img-container' div, with the width being the sum of all the images and their padding. The images and image widths are added in dynamically through a CMS, which is why I need the javascript to calculate the width dynamically.

```
<div id='img-container'[HERE IS WHERE I NEED THE WIDTH TO BE ADDED]>
<div class='picture_holder' >
<div class='picture' >
<img src="{image}" style='width:{width}px;padding-right:10px;'/>
<div class='captioning'>{caption}</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know javascript at all, but tried to piece something together (I didn't even get to adding in the padding yet):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $name = ('div#img-container');
var Imgs = div.getElementsByTagName('img');
var w = 0;
for ( var i = 0; i < Imgs.length; i++ ){
    w += parseInt(Imgs[i].offsetWidth);
}
</script>
```

It's obviously not working at all though. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: inb4 a jquery answer pops up. Oh wait, you're using a JQuery selector at `var $name = ('div#img-container');` but your question isn't tagged with with JQuery. Did you include the JQuery lib in your page yet?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use jQuery (or similar library)? Things like this are fairly trivial with a decent JavaScript library.

Comment: jQuery is more easier to handle it in this case.

Comment: Do you have more than one `img-container` div which you'd like to apply that style to or just one `img-container` div?

Answer (score 0):

The code has a bug in `var $name = ('#div ...` . You must use `document.getElementById(id-of-element)`. The `#div...`sintax is jQuery selector and as I understand, you are not using jQuery. Next, you call `div.getElementsByTagName('img') to get only the list of images inside the`div`. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function add_width_of_images(container) {
    var div = document.getElementById(container);
    if (!div) return;

    var Imgs = div.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var w = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < Imgs.length; i++ ){
        w += parseInt(Imgs[i].offsetWidth);
    }
    div.style.width = w + "px";
}
add_width_of_images('img-container');

</script>
```